# Task Automation on Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I need to run more than 100 lines SQL queries 'execute as script' at 4 am, how can schedule it on oracle toad .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Toad, under `Utilities > Task Scheduler`, you can set up a task to launch SQLPlus at a specified time. In the parameters section of the task you can specify your connection information to the database and call the SQL script.

Comment: Can you please add more details about task scheduler, the steps to run the query on the specified time

Comment: You would need to store the queries you want to run in a SQL script then launch the script like `sqlplus username/password@database @/path/to/script.sql`